# LT1970 output changes when I probe the voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm using an [LT1970](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1970fe.pdf) for current control. I read the current with a shunt resistor and an [AD8421](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8421.pdf).

When I connected the circuit to a 10 Ω load, the AD8421 read 134 mA, but when I tried to measure the voltage between loads, the current changed to 148 mA. I even get the same effect when the probe is not connected to the multimeter. What do I need to add to the circuit to make it not affected by external disturbance?

Here is my schematic:

[image]

Comment: @SASKEEEEH please edit questions instead of deleting and reposting